# How to properly call ScalablyTyped request module?

Tags: scala.js

There's a `request` module on npm which is called the following way:

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  // processing
});
```

I'm using ScalablyTyped bindings which appear to have this method defined [here](https://github.com/ScalablyTyped/Distribution/blob/4986840e202872fdec5fe113e09fc30f5a514a5a/r/request/src/main/scala/typings/request/mod/RequestAPI.scala#L8). I am trying to call it but with no luck:

```scala
import typings.request.mod.RequestAPI

RequestAPI("http://localhost:8888")
```

This leads to an error:

```
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: /home/user/Dev/Scala/scalajs-auto-cors/src/main/scala/app/TutorialApp.scala:15:4 
[error] 15 |    RequestAPI("http://localhost:8888")
[error]    |    ^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |    Not found: RequestAPI
[error]    |
[error]    | longer explanation available when compiling with `-explain`
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I'm not sure how import succeeds but method call doesn't.
What would be the right way to properly translate the JS code?